# String format and floating points

Tags: python

I am trying to reach the .17 after zero how to pick two dec after the zero in this case
i tried the old way with % but wanna discover if that possible with the .format anyone can help?

```
km = float(input('Enter "km" numbers: '))
conv_fac = 0.621371
round(miles,-2)
miles = km * conv_fac

print('{} km is equal to {} miles'.format(km, miles))
```

Output:

```
Enter "km" numbers:  3.5
3.5 km is equal to 2.1747985 miles
```

Comment: Please read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round of to two decimal places as you have attempted but you have to give the decimal point as second argument which is 2 and not -2 like below.

```
km = float(input('Enter "km" numbers: '))
conv_fac = 0.621371
miles = round(km * conv_fac,2)

print('{} km is equal to {} miles'.format(km, miles))
```

Comment: It worked very well

Comment: yeah you have to give the decimal places you need as second parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{:.2f}` to format a float with 2 digits after the decimal point:

```
print('{:.2f} km is equal to {:.2f} miles'.format(km, miles))
```

You can also use an f-string:

```
print(f'{km:.2f} km is equal to {miles:.2f} miles')
```

You don't have to call `round` before formatting the floats.

Refer to [the string formatting docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information.

Comment: Yeah this way is much better thank u